# Users that have the APK with version code 1, which targets SDK 23 or higher

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build

I developed android app with phonegap.But my user could not install it from google play store because of that error: your device isn't compatible with this version

I tried to downgrade version so I changed
minSdkVersion from 26 to 17

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="17"/>
```

but it give that error.What should I do?How can I donwgrade to 17?

Problem:

```
    Users that have the APK with version code 1, which targets SDK 23 or higher,
 will receive an error when they attempt to upgrade to this APK because it targets SDK 17.
```

Resolution:

```
 Ensure that your release includes APKs targeting SDK 23 or higher to which
all users that have the APK with version code 1 can upgrade.
```

Comment: increase your target sdk version to 26 or above , it will be good for future too

Comment: I don't think its possible to lower minSDK version after app being published to google play

Comment: @Redman nobody will install it   ;

Comment: @Taie so I should delete that app and install new one to google play ?

Comment: why will nobody install it?

Comment: without target version 26 you can't even update your app on playstore from november

Comment: @Redman OMG  ,%90 user use android version under 8.0(version 26)...so %90 user will not install apps?

Comment: I am saying about target sdk version not min sdk version  they both are different, keep min as less as possible and target sdk as high as possible

Comment: you said good thing..   I did this..is this false ?  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="26"/>   
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion"   value="17"/>

Comment: That reverse , min sdk should be 17 and targetsdk should be 26

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the difference between `minSdk` and `targetSdk` and this is a little complicated.

In version 1, you set a `minSdk` of 26. If you didn't explicitly set a `targetSdk`, that means the system will have also assumed a `targetSdk` of 26 by default to match the `minSdk`. So far so good.

Now `minSdk` represents the minimum device version of Android you can run on. `targetSdk` represents the version of the Android SDK you know about and used when developing the app. An important change happened in SDK 23. Android started supporting optional permissions - ie the app user didn't have to accept all the permissions at install time, instead they could accept them as they used the app.

So all the users you have who installed version 1 didn't accept any permissions. If in version 2 you switched to `targetSdk=17` and the users updated the app, the system would assume they had accepted the permissions at install time (because it moved back to the old permissions model), and the user would never get asked for permissions, which would be a big security hole.

So once an app in on the new permissions model (`targetSdk>=23`) it can never move back.

To get your app working you have to do the following:

- set your `minSdk` to 17 (or whatever you want it to be)
- set your `targetSdk` to 23 or greater (probably 26). The [instructions on doing this in phonegap are here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#android-targetSdkVersion)
- make sure all your code which uses permissions has correct optional permissions requests when running on devices with SDK 23 or greater.